# How to refresh in deleting board

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

prior to write,I want to apologize because I'm not good at English T.T Sorry :)

I've been implemented some Bulletin Board System(=Freeboard) by JSP, Javascript, HTML.

It consists that view pages,writing,edting,deleting,. etc.,
but while I implement the deleting System, small trouble  occurred.

the view page that i wanted to delete to is deleted, then go back the list page, but list of view page that i wanted to delete to do not disappear.

It must need  at least one more refresh(F5 key).

I want to confirm it without refresh(F5 key) right away thanks.

Regards,

----------please refer to the following  source example "bbs_delete.jsp --------

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<%@ include file="../dbinfo.jsp" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<%
String bbs_num = request.getParameter("num");
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
String SQL  = "delete from Freeboard where num = ?";
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
pstmt.setString(1, bbs_num);
pstmt.execute(); %>
<script>
alert("the deletion is completed successfully. ");
history.back(-1);
location.href("bbs_list.jsp")
</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this will work for you

`window.open("URL of page","_self")`

Use this to navigate to the page, this will redirect you to your required URL and you will not need to refresh(F5) the page.